# How to determine if expressions of sets are equal

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A question in my book asks if $A$ and $B$ are sets then determine if $\overline{A-B}=\overline{A}\cup B$ is true or not. I havent been able to solve any of these questions so I was hoping someone could help.

Comment: If you know venn diagrams, draw two venn diagrams where in one A and B are disjoint and one where they are not disjoint and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Break it into cases. For any element $x$, there are four possible cases:

- $x\in A$ and $x\in B$
- $x\not\in A$ and $x\in B$
- $x\in A$ and $x\not\in B$
- $x\not\in A$ and $x\not\in B$

Go through each case and prove that $x\in\overline{A-B}$ if and only if $x\in\overline{A}\cup B$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hints for an algebraic proof:*

For any two sets $X,Y$ in a universal set $\Omega$ you have the following properties:

$X-Y=X\cap \overline{Y}$

$\overline{X\cap Y} = \overline{X}\cup \overline{Y}$

$\overline{X\cup Y} = \overline{X}\cap \overline{Y}$

$\overline{\left(\overline{X}\right)} = X$

---

So, $\overline{A-B} = \cdots$

> $\cdots =\overline{A\cap \overline{B}}=\cdots$

$~$

> $\cdots = \overline{A}\cup \overline{(\overline{B})}=\overline{A}\cup B$